# Form of multidimensional polynomial

Tags: polynomials

In the one dimensional case, you can write a polynomial $p\in K[X]$, $p= \sum_k p_k X^k$ as $p = \sum_{k=0}^n p_k X^k$.

Why is it in the general case for $p\in K[X_1, \ldots, X_m]$, $p= \sum_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^m} p_\alpha X^\alpha$ that $p = \sum_{j=0}^n q_j(X_1, \ldots, X_{m-1}) X_m^j$, $q_j \in K[X_1, \ldots, X_{m-1}]$?

Where does the expression $q_j(X_1, \ldots, X_{m-1}) X_m^j$ come from? I guess that at least for $p\in K[X_1, \ldots, X_m]$ ,$p= \sum_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^m} p_\alpha X^\alpha$ and $\operatorname{degree}(p) = n$ then $p=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq n} p_\alpha X^\alpha$.

Comment: This is just the observation that a polynomial ring with a coefficient ring that itself is a polynomial ring is in total a polynomial ring with one variable more.

Comment: I thought that the problem is trivial but I can't make sense of the multiplication $q_j(X_1, ..., X_{m-1})*X_m^j$. Is $n$ the highest exponent of $X_m$?

Comment: Yes. Although the sum is written for all $α∈\mathbb N^m$, to get a polynomial all but finitely many of the $p_α$ have to be zero. So each variable has a maximum degree, $n=\deg_{X_m}p$. Or as in your text, $n$ is the total degree of $p$, so that all degrees of individual variables are equal or smaller $n$. Then $q_n(X_{1:m-1})=0$ is included as possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a strictly formal point of view, for instance while contemplating data structures for polynomials, the objects $K[X,Y]$ and $(K[X])[Y]$ are different. For the normal uses of algebra, this difference is about as important as the fact that you can define triples $(a,b,c)$ as pairs of pairs $((a,b),c)$.

The operation of the texts orders and groups the monomials of the polynomial by powers of $Y$. The factor of each power of $Y$ will be a polynomial in $X$. That is, an element of $K[X]$, where this polynomial ring is considered as (canonically) embedded in $K[X,Y]$.

Comment: Ah great, I got it :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm suprised. Those are relly fancy structures, I mean, you can just drop one unknown and write it as a product with the sum of the corresponding (m-1)-unknowns-polynomials and it still works fine.